# Using array values as a multiplier?

Tags: c++, string

Say I have:

```
array[i]
// and array[4] was the value of 5
// I think something like this works in C++ array[4]*array[4] would give me 25
```

Is there someway to do the same with strings or is a loop in the only way in C++, because I remember in Python you could do something similar to:

```
"string"*4
// would give you "stringstringstringstring"
```

Comment: So you want to do something like "foo" * 4 in c++? And expect what output? I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: No, C++ doesn't have anything like Python's string multiplier.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11843258/2890168

Comment: @RedAgito He shows the output he wants in the comment.